# Python Error handing for input

Tags: python, html, forms, exception

I have a form where users can input details and submit it and view what they entered on my webpage however, I want to add an error handling function where if the user doesn't enter anything inside the input field it displays and error saying `please dont leave field empty`

I have 3 fields, I want this function to apply individually to each field, so I can take one out if I need to, I have added my code hereunder:

**Python code**

```
@app.route('/personal', methods = ['POST', 'GET'])
def personal():
    query = "select * from guestbook5;"
    cur = db.execute(query)
    rv = cur.fetchall()
    print(rv)
    cur.close()
    return render_template('personal.html',rv=rv)


@app.route('/personalform',methods=['GET'])
def personalform():
    return render_template('personalform.html')

@app.route('/sign3', methods=['POST'])  
def sign3():
    country=request.form['Country']
    relationship=request.form['Relationship']
    kids=request.form['Kids']
    params = {'Country':country, 'Relationship':relationship, 'Kids':kids }
    db.execute("insert into guestbook5 values 
    (:Country,:Relationship,:Kids);",params)
    db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('personal'))
```

**html code**

```
   <form action="{{ url_for('sign3') }}" method=post>
   <dl>
    <dt>Country:
    <dd><input type=text name=Country>
    <dt>Relationship:
    <dd><input type=text name=Relationship>
    <dt>Kids:
    <dd><input type=text name=Kids>

    <dd><input type=submit value=sign>
   </dl>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit your sign3 function with the below. I added in an if statement saying that if either Country, Relationship, or Kids was empty, it would send an error message back to the user on the HTML page. The `<"post error message">` is for you to fill in the error message and link back to the HTML page.

```
country=request.form['Country']
relationship=request.form['Relationship']
kids=request.form['Kids']
if country == '' or relationship == '' or kids == '':
    <"post error message">
else:
    params = {'Country':country, 'Relationship':relationship, 'Kids':kids }
    db.execute("insert into guestbook5 values 
    (:Country,:Relationship,:Kids);",params)
    db.commit()
return redirect(url_for('personal'))
```

Comment: How can I link it back to the HTML?

Comment: All you have to do is redirect the user to a page saying "please dont leave field empty' while also indicating what was left blank

Comment: But I don't want the user to be redirected to a separate page. I want the error message to show on the page where the form is. How would the code look like?

Comment: just redirect them to a copy of the form page but with the error message.

Comment: Can you show me the code for this please. I'm just really confused, I dont want to make a separate form page just to display the error

Comment: what is the name of the html file because your code presented in the question is lacking some information

Comment: The HTML form file is called personalform.html where the comments are sent to is called personal.html

Comment: insert into the error message section a php `echo` message and tell me if you have any luck

Comment: No luck! Can I do it without the php function?

Comment: yes you can do it without the php function. I cannot do it all for you. I am giving you suggestions and pushing you in the right direction so that you learn.